# Silhouette Mountain Shader

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

How to create seamless/repetitive silhouette mountains to plane object in a procedural way?

Example mountain silhouettes shapes:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a *Noise* texture repeat on the X axis by tiling its X coordinate.

Separate your texture coordinate components with a *Separate XYZ* node, then drive the X component through a *Converter > Math > Wrap* node. Feed this as input for the vector socket s *Noise* texture.

Connect the output of noise to a *Color Mix* node, combining the other socket with the untoched Y coordinates from the *Separate XYZ* node.

Run the output through a *Color Ramp* set to *Constant*.

You can control the frequency of the tiling from the *Max* value of the *Wrap* node, the frequency of the mountain roughness from the *Noise* texture *Scale* parameter, and the range of heights from the *Mix* factor of the *Color Mix* node.

[image]

Mix more *Noise* nodes or even use different textures to get different skyline contours with varied serrated patterns.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for this clever answer.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: For the Wrap I would instead feed the X into a sine cosine pair and recombine as a 2D input for the noise such that the nasty cutoff is at 0 and 1 gets smoothed out.

Comment: Indeed, good point. I though of that too late after posting, but haven't found the time to update

Comment: you can also sampe 2d texture in a circle then its seamless. and you dont have to deal with the blending.

Comment: Also why does the noise need to repeat?

Comment: To make it tileable as per OPs requirements

Comment: Can you not use the "Cicada Principle" and combine a few periodic noises with different periods? See in CSS e.g. https://css-tricks.com/cicada-principle-css/ or https://www.sitepoint.com/the-cicada-principle-and-why-it-matters-to-web-designers/ --- if the noises have period 2, 3, and 5 then combining them gives a repeat only after 2x3x5=30 periods. If you have 2, 3, 5 and 7 it's 210periods (for only 17 periods of "content")?

Comment: That is a very interesting principle. Sounds doable, you could probably achieve that with math nodes and some elbow grease